# How to programmatically create DotNetNuke pages?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm working on a DotNetNuke site which will be used as a store.  Each product will have its own DotNetNuke page containing various modules.  I'd like to create a module that will allow an administrator to create new products.

What is the best way to go about this?  How do you programmatically create new DotNetNuke pages, populate them with modules, and configure the modules?

I'm sure this can be done, I just don't know how to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after several days I found the answer to my own question.  If anyone else is looking for a way to programatically create DotNetNuke pages, populate them with modules, and configure the modules --here's your solution!

[This blog entry](http://kemmis.info/blog/archive/2007/11/07/programmatically-creating-dotnetnuke-pages.aspx) by Rafe Kemmis was my starting point, though based on an earlier version of DNN.  He has several other DNN articles which may also be useful.

Another section of the code below was taken from the DNN source.  I did some tweaking, but it's still 99% from source.

The following is a test DNN module I put together while working on this problem.  I hope you find it useful.  Figuring it out was certainly educational.

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Reflection

Imports DotNetNuke
Imports DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions
Imports DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions
Imports DotNetNuke.Services.Localization
Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules
Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Definitions
Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Users

Namespace DNNTest.Modules.PageGenerator

    Partial Class ViewPageGenerator
        Inherits Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase

#Region "Enums"

        Private Enum ViewPermissionType
            View = 0
            Edit = 1
        End Enum

#End Region

#Region "Events"

        Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Try
                If (Not IsPostBack) Then
                    PermGrid.TabID = -1
                    ParentsDropDownList.DataSource = TabController.GetPortalTabs(PortalId, TabId, True, False)
                    ParentsDropDownList.DataBind()
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'failure
                Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Me, ex)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnAddPage_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddPage.Click
            CreatePage(Trim(txtTabName.Text), Trim(txtTabTitle.Text), Trim(txtTabDesc.Text), Trim(txtTabKeyWords.Text), PermGrid.Permissions)
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "DNN Page Creation"

        Private Sub CreatePage(ByVal PageName As String, ByVal PageTitle As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal Keywords As String, ByVal Permissions As TabPermissionCollection, Optional ByVal LoadDefaultModules As Boolean = True)
            Dim controller As New TabController
            Dim newTab As New Tabs.TabInfo
            Dim newPermissions As TabPermissionCollection = newTab.TabPermissions
            Dim permissionProvider As PermissionProvider = permissionProvider.Instance
            Dim infPermission As TabPermissionInfo

            ' set new page properties
            newTab.PortalID = PortalId
            newTab.TabName = PageName
            newTab.Title = PageTitle
            newTab.Description = Description
            newTab.KeyWords = Keywords
            newTab.IsDeleted = False
            newTab.IsSuperTab = False
            newTab.IsVisible = True
            newTab.DisableLink = False
            newTab.IconFile = ""
            newTab.Url = ""
            newTab.ParentId = CInt(ParentsDropDownList.SelectedValue)

            ' create new page
            controller.AddTab(newTab, LoadDefaultModules)

            ' copy permissions selected in Permissions collection
            For index As Integer = 0 To (Permissions.Count - 1)
                infPermission = New TabPermissionInfo

                infPermission.AllowAccess = Permissions(index).AllowAccess
                infPermission.RoleID = Permissions(index).RoleID
                infPermission.RoleName = Permissions(index).RoleName
                infPermission.TabID = Permissions(index).TabID
                infPermission.PermissionID = Permissions(index).PermissionID

                'save permission info
                newPermissions.Add(infPermission, True)
                permissionProvider.SaveTabPermissions(newTab)
            Next index

            'create module on page
            'CreateModule(newTab.TabID, "MyHTMLModule", "ContentPane", "Text/HTML")
            CreateModule(newTab.TabID, "MyModule", "ContentPane", "Custom_DNN_Module")

            ' clear the cache
            DataCache.ClearModuleCache(newTab.TabID)
        End Sub

        Private Sub CreateModule(ByVal TabID As Integer, ByVal modTitle As String, ByVal paneName As String, ByVal modDefinitionFriendlyName As String)
            'Create a completely new module on the new page 
            Dim modDefInfo As ModuleDefinitionInfo = ModuleDefinitionController.GetModuleDefinitionByFriendlyName(modDefinitionFriendlyName)
            AddNewModule(TabID, modTitle, modDefInfo.DesktopModuleID, paneName, 0, ViewPermissionType.View, "")

            'Configure Module Settings
            ConfigModuleSettings(ModuleID)
        End Sub

        Private Sub ConfigModuleSettings(ByVal ModuleID As Integer)
            Dim objModules As New ModuleController
            Dim TabModuleID As Integer = objModules.GetModule(ModuleID).TabModuleID
            objModules.UpdateTabModuleSetting(TabModuleID, "MySetting", "1")
        End Sub

#Region "From DNN Source --mostly"

        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>Adds a New Module to a Pane</summary>
        ''' <param name="align">The alignment for the Module</param>
        ''' <param name="desktopModuleId">The Id of the DesktopModule</param>
        ''' <param name="permissionType">The View Permission Type for the Module</param>
        ''' <param name="title">The Title for the resulting module</param>
        ''' <param name="paneName">The pane to add the module to</param>
        ''' <param name="position">The relative position within the pane for the module</param>
        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Sub AddNewModule(ByVal TabID As Integer, ByVal title As String, ByVal desktopModuleId As Integer, ByVal paneName As String, ByVal position As Integer, ByVal permissionType As ViewPermissionType, ByVal align As String)

            Dim objTabController As New TabController
            Dim objTabPermissions As TabPermissionCollection = objTabController.GetTab(TabID, PortalId, True).TabPermissions
            Dim objPermissionController As New PermissionController
            Dim objModules As New ModuleController
            Dim objModuleDefinition As ModuleDefinitionInfo
            Dim objEventLog As New Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController
            Dim j As Integer

            Try
                Dim desktopModule As DesktopModuleInfo = Nothing
                If Not DesktopModuleController.GetDesktopModules(PortalSettings.PortalId).TryGetValue(desktopModuleId, desktopModule) Then
                    Throw New ArgumentException("desktopModuleId")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogException(ex)
            End Try

            Dim UserId As Integer = -1
            If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
                Dim objUserInfo As Users.UserInfo = UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo
                UserId = objUserInfo.UserID
            End If

            For Each objModuleDefinition In ModuleDefinitionController.GetModuleDefinitionsByDesktopModuleID(desktopModuleId).Values
                Dim objModule As New ModuleInfo
                objModule.Initialize(PortalSettings.PortalId)

                objModule.PortalID = PortalSettings.PortalId
                objModule.TabID = TabId
                objModule.ModuleOrder = position
                If title = "" Then
                    objModule.ModuleTitle = objModuleDefinition.FriendlyName
                Else
                    objModule.ModuleTitle = title
                End If
                objModule.PaneName = paneName
                objModule.ModuleDefID = objModuleDefinition.ModuleDefID
                If objModuleDefinition.DefaultCacheTime > 0 Then
                    objModule.CacheTime = objModuleDefinition.DefaultCacheTime
                    If Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultModuleId > Null.NullInteger AndAlso Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultTabId > Null.NullInteger Then
                        Dim defaultModule As ModuleInfo = objModules.GetModule(Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultModuleId, Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultTabId, True)
                        If Not defaultModule Is Nothing Then
                            objModule.CacheTime = defaultModule.CacheTime
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                Select Case permissionType
                    Case ViewPermissionType.View
                        objModule.InheritViewPermissions = True
                    Case ViewPermissionType.Edit
                        objModule.InheritViewPermissions = False
                End Select

                ' get the default module view permissions
                Dim arrSystemModuleViewPermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionByCodeAndKey("SYSTEM_MODULE_DEFINITION", "VIEW")

                ' get the permissions from the page
                For Each objTabPermission As TabPermissionInfo In objTabPermissions
                    If objTabPermission.PermissionKey = "VIEW" AndAlso permissionType = ViewPermissionType.View Then
                        'Don't need to explicitly add View permisisons if "Same As Page"
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    ' get the system module permissions for the permissionkey
                    Dim arrSystemModulePermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionByCodeAndKey("SYSTEM_MODULE_DEFINITION", objTabPermission.PermissionKey)
                    ' loop through the system module permissions
                    For j = 0 To arrSystemModulePermissions.Count - 1
                        ' create the module permission
                        Dim objSystemModulePermission As PermissionInfo
                        objSystemModulePermission = CType(arrSystemModulePermissions(j), PermissionInfo)
                        If objSystemModulePermission.PermissionKey = "VIEW" AndAlso permissionType = ViewPermissionType.Edit AndAlso _
                             objTabPermission.PermissionKey <> "EDIT" Then
                            'Only Page Editors get View permissions if "Page Editors Only"
                            Continue For
                        End If

                        Dim objModulePermission As ModulePermissionInfo = AddModulePermission(objModule, _
                                                                                objSystemModulePermission, _
                                                                                objTabPermission.RoleID, objTabPermission.UserID, _
                                                                                objTabPermission.AllowAccess)

                        ' ensure that every EDIT permission which allows access also provides VIEW permission
                        If objModulePermission.PermissionKey = "EDIT" And objModulePermission.AllowAccess Then
                            Dim objModuleViewperm As ModulePermissionInfo = AddModulePermission(objModule, _
                                                                                CType(arrSystemModuleViewPermissions(0), PermissionInfo), _
                                                                                objModulePermission.RoleID, objModulePermission.UserID, _
                                                                                True)
                        End If
                    Next

                    'Get the custom Module Permissions,  Assume that roles with Edit Tab Permissions
                    'are automatically assigned to the Custom Module Permissions
                    If objTabPermission.PermissionKey = "EDIT" Then
                        Dim arrCustomModulePermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionsByModuleDefID(objModule.ModuleDefID)

                        ' loop through the custom module permissions
                        For j = 0 To arrCustomModulePermissions.Count - 1
                            ' create the module permission
                            Dim objCustomModulePermission As PermissionInfo
                            objCustomModulePermission = CType(arrCustomModulePermissions(j), PermissionInfo)

                            AddModulePermission(objModule, objCustomModulePermission, _
                                                                    objTabPermission.RoleID, objTabPermission.UserID, _
                                                                    objTabPermission.AllowAccess)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

                objModule.AllTabs = False
                objModule.Alignment = align

                objModules.AddModule(objModule)
            Next

        End Sub

        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>Adds a Module Permission</summary>
        ''' <param name="permission">The permission to add</param>
        ''' <param name="roleId">The Id of the role to add the permission for.</param>
        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Function AddModulePermission(ByVal objModule As ModuleInfo, ByVal permission As PermissionInfo, ByVal roleId As Integer, ByVal userId As Integer, ByVal allowAccess As Boolean) As ModulePermissionInfo
            Dim objModulePermission As New ModulePermissionInfo
            objModulePermission.ModuleID = objModule.ModuleID
            objModulePermission.PermissionID = permission.PermissionID
            objModulePermission.RoleID = roleId
            objModulePermission.UserID = userId
            objModulePermission.PermissionKey = permission.PermissionKey
            objModulePermission.AllowAccess = allowAccess

            ' add the permission to the collection
            If Not objModule.ModulePermissions.Contains(objModulePermission) Then
                objModule.ModulePermissions.Add(objModulePermission)
            End If

            Return objModulePermission
        End Function

#End Region

#End Region

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Here's the markup...

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" Inherits="DNNTest.Modules.PageGenerator.ViewPageGenerator" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" CodeBehind="ViewPageGenerator.ascx.vb" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Portal" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.Controls" Assembly="DotNetNuke" %>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Parent Tab:" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ParentsDropDownList" runat="server" DataTextField="TabName" DataValueField="TabID" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Tab Name:"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTabName" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Tab Title:"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTabTitle" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Description:"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTabDesc" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Key Words:"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTabKeyWords" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <Portal:TabPermissionsGrid ID="PermGrid" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddPage" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddPage_Click" Text="Add New Page Here" Width="161px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Old post, I know. Is this the complete solution. Unfortunately that blog has been down for a while - and I've been looking for this type of solution for a while. Just want to know if it's all I need (obviously tweaked to mine own scenario). Thanks. +1

Comment: Responding to Moriarty: I haven't worked with DNN in a few years, but I remember I posted the key parts that were needed.  Although, I don't know how DNN has changed in the meantime. I hope my old solution will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to create a page level Template.  Setup a page with all the modules you want on it. Save it / Export it as a template.  Then your user who needs to create a new product clicks Add page.  Make the page. Then just configure the module that has your product / store logic in it.  Should do the trick.

Comment: I have considered using templates, but I think that still leaves too much configuration for the users.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I don't use templates all that often, but I think if your module supports the export feature then you can have the module pre-configured as well.  SO, not sure what module you are using for your actual product.  Seems like a crazy amount of work to create a page per product in general but I have to assume you have your reasons :]

Comment: ihave to say i agree with @Ryan Doom - this seems like a crazy amount of work - many of the ecomm packages out there will do this so much more simply and the administration will be so much easier